# Let 2 single file components communicate with each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I let 2 single file components communicate with each other.

For example: I have 2 file components. `Content.vue` and a `Aside.vue`

How can i create something like, when I click on a button inside `Aside.vue` that something will update inside `Content.vue`

this is how the 2 single file compontents look inside the index.html:

```
  <div class="container articleContainer">
    <article-content></article-content>
    <article-aside></article-aside>
  </div>
```

Aside.vue:

```
<template>
  <aside>
    <span @click="updateCounter">Dit is een aside.</span>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        aside: "aside message"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Content.vue

```
<template>
  <article>
    <p>{{ counter }}</p>
    <button @click="updateCounter">Update Counter</button>
  </article>
</template>

<script>    
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        counter: 0
      }
    }
    methods: {
      updateCounter: function() {
        this.counter = this.counter + 2;
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I click on the span inside the Aside template how can I use updateCounter to update the counter inside Content.vue.

Comment: I already tried - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Maybe consider [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is not aas big or complex to use vuex , you can set up an [EventBus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) like this:

```
export const EventBus = new Vue();// in your main.js file
```

in Aside.vue:

```
<template>
  <aside>
    <span @click="updateCounter">Dit is een aside.</span>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        aside: "aside message"
      }
    },
    methods:{
        updateCounter(){
            EventBus.emit('updateCounter');
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

in Content.vue

```
<template>
  <article>
    <p>{{ counter }}</p>
    <button @click="updateCounter">Update Counter</button>
  </article>
</template>

<script>  
  import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        counter: 0
      }
    }
    created() {
        
        EventBus.on('updateCounter', () => {
            this.counter = this.counter + 2;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        updateCounter: function() {
            this.counter = this.counter + 2;
        },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Have a value in the `App.vue` that gets reflected by both the components. (That's the `this.$parent.someParentMethod(someValue);`-way, which would be mixed with `props`).

Option 2 (way easier, cleaner and best-practice): [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Communication between any components using Event Bus

Event Bus is not limited to a parent-child relation. You can share information between any components.

```
<script>
export default
    name: 'ComponentA',
    methods: {
        sendGlobalMessage() {
            this.$root.$emit('message_from_a', arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In the above ComponentA, we are firing an event “message_from_a” and passing arguments. Arguments are optional here. Any other component can listen to this event.

```
<script>
export default
    name: 'ComponentB',
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('message_from_a', (arg1, arg2) => {
            console.log('Message received');
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In ComponentB to listen an event, we have to register it first. We can do so by putting an event listener inside mounted() callback. This callback will be triggered when an event is fired from any component.

[source](https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa)